# why does my jquery function fadeOut work but slice doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make a button that views three consequent posts

when I click "view all" the three "div"s should show up

I need to make the three 'div's show up if I click the view all button
so I am using jquery here

```js
$('.posts .repeat-grid').slice(0, 3).show();
$('#view-all').on('click', function() {
  $('.posts .repeat-grid:hidden').slice(0, 1).slideDown();
  if ($('.posts .repeat-grid:hidden').length === 0) {
    $('#view-all').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posts">
  <div class="repeat-grid">1</div>
  <div class="repeat-grid">2</div>
  <div class="repeat-grid">3</div>
</div>

<div id="view-all">View All</div>
```

any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209812/discussion-on-question-by-mai-mohamed-why-does-my-jquery-function-fadeout-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Try this if that's what you mean

```js
$('#view-all').on('click', function() {
  $('.posts').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posts">
  <div class="repeat-grid">1</div>
  <div class="repeat-grid">2</div>
  <div class="repeat-grid">3</div>
</div>

<div id="view-all">View All</div>
```

Comment: I just tried it now, still the button is not working